# How to scroll core plot (iOS) automatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

i have set up graph with core plot, i want to move/ scroll it continuously left to right circularly.  if it was uiview it was like

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations: ^(void){// animation/ frame set
                                         }
                     completion:NULL];
```

Any other solution is also appreciated to scroll graph automatic with out user interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In coreplot you can use CPTAnimation like so:

```
zoomInAnimation = [CPTAnimation animate: plotSpace
                               property: @"xRange"
                          fromPlotRange: plotSpace.xRange
                            toPlotRange: plotRange
                               duration: ANIMATION_TIME
                              withDelay: 0
                         animationCurve: CPTAnimationCurveCubicInOut
                               delegate: self];
```

Lookup CPTAnimation to see how to animate other properties (decimals, float etc.).

Comment: can i make sequence of this animation?, first left to right and then right to left animation?

Comment: Create a second animation with a delay of `ANIMATION_TIME` to animate the plot range back to the original value.